# How to use a volatile vector?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stl, volatile

I want to benchmark how much time does it take to do sorting:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 100000000;
    volatile vector<volatile int> vec; vec.reserve(n);
    for(int nn = n; nn > 0; nn--) vec.push_back(nn);
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}
```

AFAIK the volatile here is necessary because otherwise the compiler would be free to optimize away the writes to this `vector` because what is written is never used. So no sorting would be actually done.

However, apparently, this won't work:

```
wtf.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
wtf.cc:8:50: error: passing ‘volatile std::vector<volatile int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  volatile vector<volatile int> vec; vec.reserve(n);
                                                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:69:0,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:65:5: note:   in call to ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
wtf.cc:9:48: error: passing ‘volatile std::vector<volatile int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  for(int nn = n; nn > 0; nn--) vec.push_back(nn);
                                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:64:0,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:939:7: note:   in call to ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = volatile int]’
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^~~~~~~~~
wtf.cc:10:17: error: passing ‘volatile std::vector<volatile int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:64:0,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:563:7: note:   in call to ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin() [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = volatile int*]’
       begin() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~~~
wtf.cc:10:28: error: passing ‘volatile std::vector<volatile int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:64:0,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:581:7: note:   in call to ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end() [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; typename std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = volatile int*]’
       end() _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
       ^~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:61,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h: In instantiation of ‘void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::deallocate(__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer, __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::size_type) [with _Tp = volatile int; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::pointer = volatile int*; __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>::size_type = long unsigned int]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/alloc_traits.h:462:9:   required from ‘static void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::deallocate(std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type&, std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::pointer, std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::size_type) [with _Tp = volatile int; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::allocator_type = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::pointer = volatile int*; std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<_Tp1> >::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:180:19:   required from ‘void std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_deallocate(std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer, std::size_t) [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = volatile int*; std::size_t = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:78:17:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
wtf.cc:8:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:125:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘volatile void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
  ::operator delete(__p);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:61,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/new:124:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void operator delete(void*)’
 void operator delete(void*) _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
      ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/vector:60:0,
                 from wtf.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘static _Tp* std::__copy_move_backward<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_move_b(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = volatile int; bool _IsMove = true]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:588:58:   required from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = volatile int*; _BI2 = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:598:5:   required from ‘_BI2 std::__copy_move_backward_a2(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with bool _IsMove = true; _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:668:48:   required from ‘_BI2 std::move_backward(_BI1, _BI1, _BI2) [with _BI1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; _BI2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1851:8:   required from ‘void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1885:25:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:1971:31:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4836:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<volatile int*, std::vector<volatile int> >]’
wtf.cc:10:29:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:570:33: error: invalid conversion from ‘volatile void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
      __builtin_memmove(__result - _Num, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
                        ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
<built-in>: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:570:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘const volatile void*’ to ‘const void*’ [-fpermissive]
      __builtin_memmove(__result - _Num, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<built-in>: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of ‘static _Tp* std::__copy_move<_IsMove, true, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(const _Tp*, const _Tp*, _Tp*) [with _Tp = volatile int; bool _IsMove = true]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:386:44:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = volatile int*; _OI = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:422:45:   required from ‘_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = true; _II = volatile int*; _OI = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:455:8:   required from ‘_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = std::move_iterator<volatile int*>; _OI = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:101:27:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<true>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<volatile int*>; _ForwardIterator = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<volatile int*>; _ForwardIterator = volatile int*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = std::move_iterator<volatile int*>; _ForwardIterator = volatile int*; _Tp = volatile int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:1263:35:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_allocate_and_copy(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _ForwardIterator = std::move_iterator<volatile int*>; _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = volatile int*; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/vector.tcc:73:40:   required from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reserve(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = volatile int; _Alloc = std::allocator<volatile int>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
wtf.cc:8:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:368:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘volatile void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]
      __builtin_memmove(__result, __first, sizeof(_Tp) * _Num);
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<built-in>: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:368:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘const volatile void*’ to ‘const void*’ [-fpermissive]
<built-in>: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void* __builtin_memmove(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’
```

Compiler errors persist if I only remove either one of the two `volatiles`. I have to remove both for the errors to stop; but, as I said above, I'm afraid this will be wrong.

If and how can I use `volatile` in the above snippet?

Comment: Think *very* carefully before using `volatile`. It will disable a lot of optimizations, but beyond that probably won't do what you think it will. Specifically it does *not* mean "thread safe". `volatile` is *almost never* the correct solution. Just saying.

Comment: Use a proper benchmarking framework like google-benchmark and `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(vec)`.

Comment: To guarantee the compiler cannot disable the sort, simply output a random element of the vector after sorting.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I know it does not make the code thread safe etc. However, as I explained, AFAIK it is necessary for benchmarks becaouse otherwise writes can be optimized away.

Comment: You can use the `argc` of `int main(int argc, char** argv)` as a `if (argc > 999) DoSomethingDummy(vec);` to prevent the optimizer from making the stuff go "poof" in a cloud of optimization.

Answer (score 3):

> How to use a volatile vector?

You can use a volatile qualified vector by not calling any of its member functions. That's not an option if you intend to sort the vector. They cannot be called, since none of them are volatile-qualified.

You cannot use a volatile qualified element type with a vector.

> AFAIK the volatile here is necessary

It's not the only way to prevent potential optimisation. Alternatively, you can actually read the sorted vector. (Technically, compiler could still replace the sorting since the result could be computed at compile time. It probably won't in practice, and can be more effectively prevented by using runtime input).